# SynaxError on a SQL command

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

EDIT: Yup I'm dumb.  Missed the typo.

I'm following along with a video in a Udacity course, and getting an error trying to run a SQL command via psycopg2.  The code is identical to the instructor's, but mine returns an error and her's doesnt.

```
import psycopg2

# establish connection to db
connection = psycopg2.connect('dbname=example')

# cursor is essentially an interface that allows you to start
# cuing up work and transactions
cursor = connection.cursor()

# defines SQL transaction
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE table2 (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFUALT False
    );
''')

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table2 (id, completed) VALUES (1, true);')

# commits the transaction
connection.commit()

# must manually close your session each time one is opened
connection.close()
cursor.close()
```

Error:

```
$ python3 demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "DEFUALT"
LINE 4:         completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFUALT False
```

Comment: You mean DEFAULT, not DEFUALT

Comment: Yup, it had a time minimum after asking when I tried to do it, had to wait 

Comment: No problem thanks! @BrandonZemel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a typo instead of `DEFAULT` you have written `DEFUALT`

```sql
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE table2 (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT False
    );
''')
```